# Any API or apps to scan barcode receipts?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, scanning

Are there bar code scanner apps which can scan store receipts so that we can see what purchases that we have made on a particular store? I see that Walmart's mobile app can be used to do so. Is this something store specific or can we do it for all store receipts in general?

Comment: You ought to at least mention what platform you're working with.  Are you hoping for a barcode scanning API for the Atari 800?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the barcodes is usually just a matter of scanning the defined code type.

Translating the results of that scan into anything useful is store-specific and unlikely to be successful. The information in the barcode is almost always a lookup into the store system, not enumerated receipt item data.